# Natural sorting of PHP array in reverse and not preserving keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm look to naturally sort an array, in reverse order and not preserve the keys. For example, I'd like this array:

```
[0] => 1-string
[1] => 2-string
[2] => 10-string
[3] => 4-srting
[4] => 3-srting
```

To end up like this:

```
[0] => 10-srting
[1] => 4-string
[2] => 3-string
[3] => 2-string
[4] => 1-string
```

I've got it close with usort($array, 'strnatcmp'); but it's not in reverse order. array_reverse() after doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that natural or unnatural ordering?  I thought natural was "counting" so it would be `1-string, 10-string, 2-string, 3-string, 4-string` and unnatural would be `4-string, 3-string, 2-string, 10-string, 1-string`.  I have been known to misunderstand things (as i am married and miscommunications happen 24/7), so could you give a more in depth explanation, for i do not understand your ordering system.

Comment: Natural is 1, 2, 3, 4, 10—which I can do. I now need to get that in reverse order, so: 10, 4, 3, 2, 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled about "array_reverse() after doesn't help." because

```
<?php
echo PHP_VERSION, "\n";

$x = array( 
    '1-string',
    '2-string',
    '10-string',
    '4-srting',
    '3-srting'
);

natsort($x);
$x = array_reverse($x, false);
print_r($x);
```

prints

```
5.3.8
Array
(
    [0] => 10-string
    [1] => 4-srting
    [2] => 3-srting
    [3] => 2-string
    [4] => 1-string
)
```

on my machine

Answer (score 5):

Use the `$preserveKeys` attribute of [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/array_reverse) to reset the keys as well as reversing the array after a [`natcasesort()`](http://php.net/natcasesort).

```
function rnatcasesort(&$array) {
    natcasesort($array);
    $array = array_reverse($array, false);
}

$values = array('1-string', '2-string', '10-string', '4-string', '3-string');

rnatcasesort($values);

var_dump($values);

/*
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "10-string"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "4-string"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "3-string"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "2-string"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "1-string"
}
*/
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Use [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag.

```
rsort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

`SORT_NATURAL` was introduced in PHP 5.4. If you are on a lower version, go with the array_reverse(natsort()) version.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<?php
$arr  = array("1-string", "2-string", "10-string","4-srting", "3-srting");

function sort_reverse($a, $b){
  $a = (int)$a;
  $b = (int)$b;
  if ($a > $b){
    return -1;
  }
  if ($a < $b){
    return 1;
  }
   return 0;
}
usort($arr, "sort_reverse");
var_dump($arr);
```

pad here http://codepad.org/6dn81S3f

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$array = array('1-string', '2-string', '10-string', '4-string', '3-string');
natsort($array);
$array = array_reverse($array);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function to first do a natural sort and then by using array_reverse to make it in descending order

```
    function natrsort($array)
    {
      natsort($array);
      return array_reverse($array);
    }
    natrsort($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't `rsort($array)` fits your need?

Comment: Nope. That gets me 4, 3, 2, 10, 1.